# why cant i see any output in the two divs?

Tags: html, css

I cant see any output in my left and right divs.I can only see the header and footer but not the rest.I am a beginner so please try to answer in simple terms.
Kindly try to point out the error/bug instead of altering the code.

```css
#header {
  height: 50px;
  width: 1600px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: Aquamarine;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}
.left {
  height: 500px;
  width: 700px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: Lavenderblush;
  float: left;
}
.right {
  height: 500px;
  width: 700px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  float: right;
}
#footer {
  height: 50px;
  width: 1600px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: Yellow;
  clear: both;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  color: Blue;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
h4 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  color: Blue;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>My Resume</h1>
</div>
<div class="left">
  <p>Hello how are u</p>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <p>some random data here</p>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <h4>This is the footer</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't loaded this code but likely, your fixed header with a height of 50 is hiding the text you're expecting to see. You could add a margin-top: 50px to .left and .right so they clear the fixed header.

Answer (score 1):

The header is `position: fixed` so it is taken out of normal flow (i.e. it doesn't influence the start position of content outside it) and *covers* the top of the content that immediately follows it.